# Adding multiple svn repositories to trac 0.12

Tags: svn, trac, post-commit-hook

We are running trac 0.12.
From what I have read it should be possible to add more than one svn repository to trac starting with this version.
Does this mean I can connect multiple repositories to the same trac environment even? Assuming I have a repo called repo1 already and I wish to add a repo2.
Is the following the correct way of doing this

- 1 In the web gui add the new repository with name repo2 and path to repo2.
- 2 svnadmin  repository resync repo2
- 3 Add the post commit hook:
  @C:\Python27\Scripts\trac-admin.exe  changeset added "%1" "%2" to hooks in repo2
  Am i correct in assuming that this will not cause trac to clear the cache of commits from the other repo1?
  Repo1 is called (default) in trac, will I need to change this or will it continue working as is?

Answer (score 1):

The resync command in step 2 is:

```
trac-admin /path/to/env repository resync "repo2"
```

Your other steps look good. Sync'ing a changeset for a single repository will not affect the cache of commits in other repositories.  "repo1" should continue to work as is.

More documentation [here](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/0.12/TracRepositoryAdmin).